# The post recover password service doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, passwords, reset

The rest of the app works, when I send request to get the password reset email, nothing happens and in the app it says, user not registered.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/index";
import { ApiClientService } from "./my-api";
import { AuthenticationService } from "./authentication.service";
import {
  GeneralResponse,
  RecoverPasswordRequest
} from "./mykujtesa-api/models";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class PasswordService {
  constructor(
    private apiClientService: ApiClientService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  public postRecoverPassword(
    request: RecoverPasswordRequest
  ): Observable<GeneralResponse> {
    return this.apiClientService.postRecoverPassword(
      this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationToken(),
      request
    );
  }
}
```

No errors in the console.

Comment: did you check the payload you sent and the server response for that?

Comment: show your `getAuthenticationToken` code.

Comment: public getAuthenticationToken() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    if (user) {
      return user.token;
    }
    return null;
  }

Comment: Are you sure the access token is still valid? if you're recovering your password I assume you aren't logged in, so maybe the local storage is empty or has a non valid access token (expired)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's valid. And yes I'm logged out

Comment: <button
      class="button button--red font-size"
      (click)="sendResetEmail()"
      [disabled]="isDisabled"
    >
      Send Email
    </button>

----------------------------------------


async sendResetEmail() {
    this.isDisabled = true;
    const result = await this.passwordService
      .postRecoverPassword(this.request)
      .toPromise();
    if (result) {
      this.isErrorMessage = !result.success;
      this.message = result.message;
      this.isDisabled = false;
    }
  }


It simply won't send an email to the user

Comment: Please re-edit the codes in the question instead of reply in comments

Comment: I think you can't trust access token to recover a password, because  there are two possible scenarios  1) Access token is valid, then a log in shouldn't be necessary and he could skip it. 2) Access token is invalid or don't have any access token, then you can't retrieve the user e-mail with that access token (you may do it if you save historical sessions with expired tokens only)

Comment: @HsuanLee I'm trying to edit it, I'm new in stack overflow.

Comment: @JoseCarlosPB That makes sense. Any suggestions

Comment: Instead of retrieving the e-mail from the acces token, the user introduce the email and you check on the backend if you have any user with that email, if thats true you can send the email.  Some websites use extra security measures like a secret question or ask for the last password user remember, thats up to you